# Rounding while checking parameters

Tags: java, rounding

I have manage to be-able to check the input and tell if its an int or not, and re ask the user if it is not.
However I want to add in a check that will convert doubles into ints by rounding them. I played around with the Math.round method, but could not get anything working properly.

```
public static int getInteger(String prompt)
{
    int input = 0;
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.print("Enter a integer: ");

    while (!user_input.hasNextInt()) { 
        System.out.println("Is not a valid number.");
        user_input.next(); 
    }


    return input;
}
```

Would be great if someone could show me how, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int getInteger()
{
    int input = 0;
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.print("Enter a integer: ");

    while (!user_input.hasNextInt() && !user_input.hasNextDouble()) {
        System.out.println("Is not a valid number.");

        user_input.next();
    }

    if(user_input.hasNextInt()) {
        input = user_input.nextInt();
    }
    else {
        input = Math.round((float) user_input.nextDouble()); //I assume here that your number is small as you said
    }

    return input;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, exactly what I wanted, only had to add in some prints.

Answer (score 0):

Math.round(double) returns a long. So, in order to transform that to an int you need to do:

```
int value = (int) Math.round(double);
```

However, I would suggest in such case to use long instead of int, as the value may not fit into an int:

```
long value = Math.round(double);
```

On the other side, Math.round(float) will return an int.

Comment: a double might not fit in a long either.

Comment: The requirement is that it checks for an int... so it has to stay as an int, its never going to get some massive number etc, its just some simple stuff for practice/study.